# Calendar:Month_List to display only months that contain events

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I am using the following code to display an archived list of months from my calendar with clickable links.

```
<ul>
    {exp:calendar:month_list date_range_start="{today}"}
        <li>
            <a href="{path='events/archives'}/{month format="%Y/%m"}"/>
                {month format="%F, %Y"}
            </a>
        </li>   
    {/exp:calendar:month_list}
</ul>
```

I only want to display months that have events in them. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

The **[`{exp:calendar:cal}`](https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/cal/)** tag can do a lot in Calendar: it's the first go-to tag to consider. I would use it since it provides a `{month_event_total}` variable you could use here. For example:

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="2015-01-01" date_range_end="2015-12-31"}
    {display_each_month}
        {if month_event_total > 0}
            // Your month header
        {/if}
    {/display_each_month}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

That should just display months that have events in them.